# Google Apps mailserver - works fine for < 50 messages; problems when sending more

Tags: asp.net

My asp.net (mvc2) web app webinar registration system sends emails with connection info. Currently we just loop thru the list of attendees and hit a System.Net.Mail.SendMail for each. We send mail via our GoogleApps account (non-premium).

My use case is to send < 50 emails at a time and the system's been working fine. On the occasions where the number pushes a 100 addresses I find error returns with the message:

Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (MAIL) g31sm4823143ibh.4

Is this message specific to Google's servers (searched on the phrase - seems like 'no'). Is there a recognized 'best practice' for sending emails by code?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that gmail just notices that you're sending a lot of messages in a rapid rate indicating it to them you're a spammer (in their eyes)?

If you have hosting I suggest you talk with your provider and see what they can offer you or provide an email address with which you can send more messages, in a controlled way of course.

Comment: Further experience with this problem convinces me that this isn't spam detection at work. Immediately after hitting the problem, i'm still able to send messages 'one-at-a-time'. Likewise...i don't think it's happening due to a cap on # of messages.

Answer (score 0):

GMail definately has a sending limit.

I dont think its widely publicised, but it certainly sounds like you're hitting it.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly old question for a followup, but to help others landing here, things have changed since then (and they constantly change):

A registered G Suite user can't relay more than 10,000 messages in a 24-hour period, and can't relay messages to more than 10,000 unique recipients per 24-hour period. Users exceeding either of these limits see the error "550 5.4.5 Daily SMTP relay limit exceeded for user."

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491#sendinglimitsforrelay